# How To Parse An Input File

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

So I need to parse this input file and I can't seem to figure out how to go about doing so. I've tried using `scanner.Delimiter()` but still having problems. Any one how any idea how to properly do this?

Here is one line from the input file:

> 200.88.223.98 - - [01/Feb/2007:04:02:22 -0500] "GET /gallery/v/events/album02/contests/programmingContest05/?g2_GALLERYSID=3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_fromNavId=x332be852 HTTP/1.1" 200 52464 "http://cs.tcnj.edu/gallery/main.php?g2_view=comment.AddComment&g2_itemId=664&g2_return=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.tcnj.edu%2Fgallery%2Fv%2Fevents%2Falbum02%2Fcontests%2FprogrammingContest05%2F%3Fg2_GALLERYSID%3D3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_GALLERYSID=3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_returnName=album" "Opera/6.01 (Windows 98; U) [en]"

It is suppose to break into sections as such:

1. `address = 200.88.223.98`
2. `date = 01/Feb/2007:04:02:22 -0500`
3. `request = GET /gallery/v/events/album02/contests/programmingContest05/?g2_GALLERYSID=3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_fromNavId=x332be852 HTTP/1.1`
4. `status = 200`
5. `bytes = 52464`
6. `refer = http://cs.tcnj.edu/gallery/main.php?
   g2_view=comment.AddComment&g2_itemId=664&g2_return=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.tcnj.edu%2Fgallery%2Fv%2Fevents%2Falbum02%2Fcontests%2FprogrammingContest05%2F%3Fg2_GALLERYSID%3D3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_GALLERYSID=3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_returnName=album`
7. `agent = Opera/6.01 (Windows 98; U) [en]`

Here is the part of my code attempting to parse it:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
scan.useDelimiter("[-']+");
while (scan.hasNextLine()) 
{
    String address = scan.next();
    String date = scan.next();
    String request = scan.next();
    int status = scan.nextInt();
    int bytes = scan.nextInt();
    String refer = scan.next();
    String agent = scan.next(); 
}
```

The following error is shown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException      
  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840) 
  at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461) 
  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091) 
  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050) 
  at Analyzer.start(Unknown Source) 
  at Driver.main(Unknown Source) 
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: What are the actual problems that you are encountering?

Comment: Is the data always going to conform to the same pattern? If so, perhaps a regular expression is the answer.

Comment: & each line of data could be different. Some might be missing one or more of those fields, each line could be a different length, etc

Comment: Can this be accomplished with regex somehow??

Answer (score 0):

Just think about this.
Split your line by space and extracting data

```
String s = "200.88.223.98 - - [01/Feb/2007:04:02:22 -0500] \"GET /gallery/v/events/album02/contests/programmingContest05/?g2_GALLERYSID=3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_fromNavId=x332be852 HTTP/1.1\" 200 52464 \"http://cs.tcnj.edu/gallery/main.php?g2_view=comment.AddComment&g2_itemId=664&g2_return=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.tcnj.edu%2Fgallery%2Fv%2Fevents%2Falbum02%2Fcontests%2FprogrammingContest05%2F%3Fg2_GALLERYSID%3D3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_GALLERYSID=3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_returnName=album\" \"Opera/6.01 (Windows 98; U) [en]\"";

  String arr [] = s.split(" ");

  for(int i =0 ;i<arr.length;i++){
      System.out.println(i+" - "+arr[i]);
  }
```

And Out put is :

```
0 : 200.88.223.98
1 : -
2 : -
3 : [01/Feb/2007:04:02:22
4 : -0500]
5 : "GET
6 : /gallery/v/events/album02/contests/programmingContest05/?g2_GALLERYSID=3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_fromNavId=x332be852
7 : HTTP/1.1"
8 : 200
9 : 52464
10 : "http://cs.tcnj.edu/gallery/main.php?g2_view=comment.AddComment&g2_itemId=664&g2_return=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.tcnj.edu%2Fgallery%2Fv%2Fevents%2Falbum02%2Fcontests%2FprogrammingContest05%2F%3Fg2_GALLERYSID%3D3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_GALLERYSID=3be9666f9c07e16b7f33e2ea8acb8dd2&g2_returnName=album"
  11 : "Opera/6.01
  12 : (Windows
  13 : 98;
  14 : U)
  15 : [en]"
```

So that 0th element give your ip , 3rd and 4th give your date, 6th and 7nt give your request , so on you can extract your data.

Comment: When I try to extract the data I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and I don't know why